# how can make my xml images fit for all devices?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

I'm new to designing of android, So I want my main screen images fit to all devices i want this MainScreen page fit to be in all devices. It has 3 images I have given weight but nothing seems to work if I test it on tab. Its not looking the way I want, here is the image

[image]

here is my XML .I know I should not give dp for height but how to make it look like that without giving sizes.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    tools:context="com.example.zeba.broccoli.MainActivity" >


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:weightSum="1">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ms1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="374dp"
                android:layout_weight="7"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/avatar" />


        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            >


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ms2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"

                android:src="@drawable/ee"

                android:layout_weight=".5" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ms3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/dd"
                android:layout_weight=".5" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Fixed dimensions for Images can be vary with devices. Use _wrap_content_ for dimensions and tell your designer to design images according to different screen resolutions.

Comment: If you don't want to give sizes then you need to place  images of different sizes in separate drawable folders i.e. drawable-xhdpi,drawable-xxhdpi and so on

Comment: if i resize the image according to devices like hdpi, xxhdpi..like that..thn it can be fit?

Comment: thts ok but here i can give my image perfect look without giving height size ..eg here i have given 374dp..which i shud not given

Comment: i want to build with weight..but weight is nt working here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.7">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ms1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />


            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.3">


                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ms2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight=".5"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ms3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight=".5"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: I have replace your image resource with ic_launcher.so put accordingly as per your need. Thanks.

Comment: but i need to do work on size as for some device the image is going out nt fitting properly..may be need to adjust with size

Comment: It will adjust automatically. Just test with more devices.You will get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

See following xml solution to get what you need.

You always can change relative width and height of the each view element by playing layout_weight parameter. Its like give width/height in percents :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@android:drawable/btn_default"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_weight="70"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="30">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@android:drawable/btn_default"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@android:drawable/btn_default"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```